# Run Neo4j query REST API through PHP

Tags: php, rest, api, neo4j

I have a small cypher query to run through PHP and I have 2 questions:

1.Where should I run this code? In Neo4j browser or a normal localhost
    like WAMP?

2.If I want to use REST API, does JSON library have to be included?

```
       <?php
            $data_json = json_encode($data);

            $curl= curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_PORT => "7474",
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST"
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "query = MATCH (n: Director) Return id(n) LIMIT 1",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Basic sjEwKEl5bx3kdFLeLSEeIqD=",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
     $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
```